# How to send data through anchor tag in php?

Tags: php

I am trying to send user_id and user_name as query string to another page through an anchor tag. **I have to send two information user_id and user_name.** I have tried several time but it is somewhat not working

here is my code:

```
      $single_id = 30;
      $user_name = 'jhon';
```

And my query string is:

```
               echo '<a href="view-transaction.php?entry_id='.$single_id.'
                ">'.$user_name.'</a>';
```

**I have to include just user_name as query string user_name.**

Any kind of help will be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: You mentioned user_id twice but your code uses "entry_id", maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concat everything properly, especially the query string. Query strings start with a `?` and each subsequent key value pair is appended with an ampersand `&`:

```
echo '<a href="view-transaction.php?entry_id='.$single_id.'&user_name=' . $user_name .'">'.$user_name.'</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the username in the query string. Like so:

```
echo '<a href="view-transaction.php?entry_id='.$single_id.'&user_name=' . $user_name .'">'.$user_name.'</a>';
```

Comment: and then use `$_GET['user_name']` and `$_GET['entry_id']` on `view-transaction.php` page to see the values.